UIList with checkmarks (one on all others off)
I have an UIList in which I display a PropertyGroup defined like this:
class CUSTOM_PG_library_list(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
  lib_name: bpy.props.StringProperty(name ="lib_name")
  lib_last_mod: bpy.props.IntProperty(name ="lib_last_mod")
  lib_active: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="lib_active", default=False)
    
class CUSTOM_UL_items(UIList):
    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
        checkbox = "CHECKBOX_HLT" if item.lib_active else "CHECKBOX_DEHLT"
        split = layout.split(factor=0.1)
        split.prop(item, "lib_active", text="", emboss=False, icon=checkbox)
        split.label(text=item.lib_name)

I never worked with UILists so I have a bit of a hard time to understand how they work.
In the UiList, I would like to be able to only set one checkmark at any time. (Switching the others off).
Unfortunately, toggling the checkmark on or off is a different action as selecting one line in the UIList.
Is it possible to bind the click on an UIList line (name or checkmark doesn't matter) together?
So if I click on a line it toggles the checkmark belonging to that line to on but also turns all other off.
(One needs to be selected, so there can not be a state where all are off.)
How can I achieve this? Do I need an update function to lib_active or some sort of an update function to the UIList itself?
EDIT:
Here is the call from the UI:
layout.template_list("CUSTOM_UL_items", "", self, "lib_list", self, "lib_list_index", rows=2)

The look should be like this:

What I would like to avoid is this:

(UIList selection and Set Checkmark are mismatched.)
I don't know how to "synchronize" the click on a list with the state of a checkmark. For example, I can toggle the checkmark without selecting the list, which is also not what I want. Checkmark and active line in UIList should be always the same.

if i understood you right, you don't want a checkmark, but more an enum value, is that right?

Note the data.active_propname value is changed when you click on a UI list element. Where do you store it ? How do you call the ui list template in your layout code ?

I updated the question with the UI call and with some clarification on what I want.
@Chris : No, I want the checkmark but always in sync with the selected UIList line.
I have some more data in the PropertyGroup which will be displayed, so it is not just the name and the checkmark.

@Gorgious This UIList is shown in my Add-On's preferences. The question is a follow up to my other question:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/316781/variable-length-list-in-preferences-displayed-as-ui-list-with-a-selection-check  Dealing with Preferences in combination with UIList is very hard for a beginner as there is very little documentation especially on UILists.  Outside of the preferences where the SCENE is used for data it is much easier.

preferences.lib_list_index is the index of the selected item in your UI list.
You can directly use that to display a checkbox when drawing your item.
class CUSTOM_UL_items(UIList):
    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname):
        # The for loop is used to retrieve the current item index in the list
        for i, list_item in enumerate(data.lib_list):
            if list_item == item:
                break
        split = layout.split(factor=0.1)
        checkbox = "CHECKBOX_HLT" if i == getattr(active_data, active_propname) else "CHECKBOX_DEHLT"
        split.label(text="", icon=checkbox)
        split.label(text=item.lib_name)


Thank you! When I test it, I get the index number of the selected item instead of a checkbox. What do I do wrong?
Also, could you explain what the for loop does? Do active_data and active_propname contain the selected line in the UIList?

So, the for is to loop trough the amount of entries in lib_list and it breaks when it is the same position as the index from the UIList active item. This I think I understand, but i is an integer. Does getattr gives back a "positional" integer where it finds the active_propname in the active_data?

@Steve you understood well. I made a mistake, layout.prop can't show an icon IIRC for an integer field. You can simply set a label with the icon. See my modified answer

Fantastic, thanks! I put a "print(active_data, active_propname)" statement inbetween and it showed lib_list_index as active_propname. I just didn't know how to handle it and change it to lib_active or any other way to display the checkmark. Your modified solution is very simple and elegant! I keep forgetting that the draw_item function is a constant loop.

I'm still confused by the UIList... :-(  Where can I put additional code that should be executed when the user clicks on one of the rows? I need to set lib_active in my Property_Group to True on the one item the user clicked but to false on all other items. The code in the UIList is a constant loop, so there is no point constantly setting some variables there. Is there a function that is called when a user clicked on a list item?

@Steve you can add an update callback to the active index lib_list_index: bpy.props.IntProperty(update=on_index_change) see https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.IntProperty

Many thanks! I really appreciate it. Now it looks exactly how I wanted it and now I also understand the logic behind UILists.

Sorry to ask again, but I found one more thing I can't figure out: how can I deselect everything in the drawn UIList? When I make a bpy.context.preferences.addons['My-AddON'].preferences.lib_list.clear() before reloading the content, it turns all lib_active to False but the UIList is still showing the last selection. So in the class where I reload my library content, I would also need to clear the UIList. How can I do that from another class?

Looks like it's a problem of refreshing the interface. Logically, clearing the lib_list should be enough to clear the UIList and remove the list content but it's not. The UI only changes when I move my mouse over the UIList. Then it get's redrawn and the list items get cleared. Is there a way to force a redraw of the UIList after I clear lib_list? I have another UIList in my Add-On which works on scene properties and there I have a clear button which clears the corresponding PropertyGroup. There, I don't have any refresh problems only in the Preferences window.

I was able to solve it by adding lib_list_index = -1 after lib_list.clear(). This way the selection in the UIList is cleared. I don't know if this is the "proper" way to do it but it doesn't complain and there are no error messages.
